# Issue in deleting a parent-child object in Hibernate "deleted object would be re-saved by cascade"

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-cascade

I have the following two entities:

**1- Deal**

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "deal", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch( FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<DealCheckList> dealCheckList;
```

**2- DealCheckList**

```
@JoinColumn(name = "DEAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "DEAL_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
private Deal deal;
```

While doing `session.delete(deal)` I am getting the below error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations):
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

That probably means that the object you are trying to delete is a child of some other collection. Setting up cascade="all" for the object means that its children would be deleted/updated automatically unless they don't belong to some other parent.

you have to remove the object you are trying to delete from its parent collection.

Example:

```
objectBeingDeleted.getParent().getChildren().remove(objectBeingDeleted);
```

and then you can do

```
session.delete(objectBeingDeleted);
```

Good Luck

Comment: can you please provide the code snippet as per my problem with what should be done before calling delete on parent object? This issue is getting on my nerves now.

Comment: is doing deal.getDealCheckList().remove(deal); right? or should i do is doing deal.getDealCheckList().clear();?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `DealCheckList` object that still references this deal and need to remove it from there in Java before deleting the deal by a hibernate call.

Comment: can you please provide the code snippet  as per my problem with what should be done before calling delete on parent object? This issue is getting on my nerves now.

Comment: If you post a bit more of the code you've got around this, I can try.  But it's probably reasonably close to what Abdel put in his answer.

Comment: is doing deal.getDealCheckList().remove(deal); right? or should i do is doing deal.getDealCheckList().clear();?

Comment: As every `DealCheckList` entry seems to have a reference back to the deal, you likely want the `clear()`.